# Does data binding support nested properties in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am writing the test application in Windows Forms. It has a simple form with TextBox and needs to implement DataBinding. I have implemented the class FormViewModel to hold my data, and have 1 class for my business data — TestObject.

Business Data object:

```
public class TestObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _testPropertyString;
    public string TestPropertyString
    {
        get
        {
            return _testPropertyString;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_testPropertyString != value)
            {
                _testPropertyString = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TestPropertyString");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class FormViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TestObject _currentObject;
    public TestObject CurrentObject
    {
        get { return _currentObject; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentObject != value)
            {
                _currentObject = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentObject");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Property:

```
private FormViewModel _viewModel;
public FormViewModel ViewModel
{ 
    get
    {
        if (_viewModel == null)
            _viewModel = new FormViewModel();

        return _viewModel;
    }
}
```

So now I'm trying to bind my data to TextBox like this:

```
TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ViewModel, "CurrentObject.TestPropertyString");
```

And surprisingly, it doesn't work! Nothing changes, when I change CurrentObject, or change TestPropertyString property.

But it works great, when I use:

```
TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ViewModel.CurrentObject, "TestPropertyString");
```

---

**So my question is: Does data binding support nested properties?**

Thank you for explanations!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Databinding` behavior was changed in .NET 4.0.  Your code works on .NET 3.5.  I found this issue posted at Microsoft Connect: [.Net 4.0 simple binding issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/05ece84a-a1d3-430c-a727-0d3665198a4b)

Here was the work-around that worked for me.  Use a `BindingSource` as the data object:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(_viewModel, null);

//textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _viewModel, "CurrentObject.TestPropertyString");
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "CurrentObject.TestPropertyString");
```

Comment: So I will not be able to use it in such way: "CurrentObject.TestPropertyString"? What is the alternative to my code in WinForms?

Comment: @MaksimGladkov I updated the answer with working code.  Maybe you didn't have something declared property.

Comment: Strange, but this doesn't work for me. Nothing happens anyway.

Comment: @MaksimGladkov I copied your code as is.  The only thing I changed was the declaration from `ViewModel" to my `_ViewModel`.  You didn't post any code showing how you declared your `ViewModel` and `TestModel` objects — maybe something is amiss there.

Comment: My ViewModel declaration is just "private FormViewModel _viewModel;". Everything is just as yours... What .NET version are you using?

Comment: @MaksimGladkov I wasn't aware that Microsoft changed the data binding implementation.  The code above works in VS2008 .NET 3.5, but when I tested it on C# 2010 Express .NET 4.0, it didn't work.  I get a `Cannot bind to property...` error.  Goofy.

Comment: @MaksimGladkov I found the issue over at Microsoft Connect and posted an update.