# C# Databound Label wont refresh

Tags: c#, data-binding, refresh, auto-update

I am databinding an object value to a label and it wont refresh.

```
lblTime.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", AppSettings.Instance.SelectedAuction, "EndDate", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

The bind works and using a messagebox, I know the value is changing. I am correctly using the INotifyChanged but it wont work.
Changing individual values works, say:

```
AppSettings.Instance.SelectedAuction.EndDate = ((Auction)lbAuctions.SelectedItem).EndDate;
```

But I want to replace the whole object, and it wont update:

```
AppSettings.Instance.SelectedAuction = (Auction)lbAuctions.SelectedItem;
```

Why is this? I can make individual values refresh but not the object itself...

```
public Auction SelectedAuction
    {
        get { return this.selectedAuction; }
        set
        {
            this.CheckPropertyChanged<Auction>
            ("SelectedAuction", ref this.selectedAuction, ref value);
        }
    }
```

Is it that there is another method to use when replacing the object itself or something additional i need to ref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data binding that is setup on `lblTime` is set on the object reference by `AppSettings.Instance.SelectedAuction` at the time of the call to `AddBinding`.  The databinding subscribes to the `PropertyChanged` event on that object.  Changing the `SelectedAuction` on your `Instance` doesn't change that.  The data binding is still subscribed on the original object.  (This also means you have a memory lead, since the data binding references the original `CurrentAuction`, that instance will not be garbage collected)

You need to instead setup the data binding so that it can listed for events on the `Instance` object.  You would have to set the binding to `"CurrentAuction.EndDate"`.  This will not work directly (* see note below), but there is a helper object, [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx), that can be put in the middle that will support that binding.  Below is an example:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = AppSettings.Instance;
lblTime.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "CurrentAuction.EndDate", false, 
      DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Note: It will work without a `BindingSource` in 3.5, but not in 4.0, see [Does data binding support nested properties in Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894103/does-data-binding-support-nested-properties-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Thanks - It feels like a step forward but its still not refreshing.. I have a listbox that shows a list of them with a datasource in the same way - but this just wont work...

Comment: Ah - WORKING. My listbox index changed event had come undone ?! Set it again and its of course working.