# How can I create a databinding for a control's nested property?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Consider the following:

```
public interface IHaveProperties
{
    public MyProperties Properties { get; set; }
}

public class MyControlA : SomeWinFormsControl, IHaveProperties { ... }

public class MyControlB : SomeOtherWinFormsControl, IHaveProperties { ... }

public class MyProperties
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public double Baz { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This allows us to add the same additional properties to a lot of different controls whose [base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) we can't modify, as well as save/load sets of properties.

Now that we have about a dozen different MyControlX, we've realized it would be nice to be able to data bind to, say, `Properties.Bar`.

Obviously we could do it like this:

```
public interface IHaveProperties
{
    public MyProperties Properties { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class MyControlA : SomeWinFormsControl, IHaveProperties
{
    public string Bar
    {
        get { return Properties.Bar; }
        set { Properties.Bar = value; }
    }
}
```

...but we would have to put that same code in each of the dozen or so controls, which seems kind of smelly.

We tried this:

```
// Example: bind control's property to nested datasource property
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", myDataSet, "myDataTable.someColumn"))
// works!

// bind control's (nested) Properties.Bar to datasource
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Properties.Bar", someObject, "AProperty"))
// throws ArgumentException!
```

Is there some way to bind to `myControl.Properties.Bar` by constructing the binding a certain way or modifying the `MyProperties` class, rather than making identical changes to all the controls?

Comment: Aa a minimum I think you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on both sides.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894103/does-data-binding-support-nested-properties-in-windows-forms

Comment: @Maarten Yep. That question covers property nesting on the datasource side of the binding, while mine is about property nesting on the control side.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't it be this:

```
TextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", someObject, "Properties.Bar"));
```

Comment: No. The problem is that I want to bind myTextBox.Properties.Bar to someObject.AProperty.