# Binding on CollectionViewSource -> View -> Groups -> Count (Code vs XAML)

Tags: binding, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

I'm trying to bind to a CollectionViewSource nested property (CVS.View.Groups.Count) and it doesn't seem to work in code :

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("View.Groups.Count");
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
binding.Source = CVS;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, binding);
```

But it's working well in WPF/xaml.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CVS.View.Groups.Count, Mode=OneWay}" Value="1">
```

So I'm wondering what is the difference between these both approach and what is wrong in code way binding. Meanwhile this kind of code is working well on no-nested property when it's a simple dependency property in a dependency object, so I suppose there is a problem with provided PropertyPath..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in resolve the problem by changing the binding source. Instead of passing the dependency object directly I create a Windows.Forms.BindingSource with the dependency object and I set this object as source of binding. In this way the binding is now working well.

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("View.Groups.Count");
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bs = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(DevicesInAlarmCVS, null);
binding.Source = bs;

BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, binding);
```

It seems to be linked to a change in .NET framework 4.0 : 
[Does data binding support nested properties in Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894103/does-data-binding-support-nested-properties-in-windows-forms)

Hope that's can help