# Issue of propertyChanged update for all subproperty in a class in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, inotifypropertychanged

I implemented a model class and want to raise PropertyChanged events for all subproperty when the object is modified. But I found it 's not working. When I push the button, the label's text is't changed.Does i miss something?I got this from MSDN -**"The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs."**
the platform is .net framework 4.0 and VS2015

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Model = new Model()
        {
            data = new User()
            {
                Name = "test"
            }
        };
        label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Model.data, "Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
    private Model model;
    public Model Model
    {
        get
        {
            return this.model;
        }
        set
        {
            model = value;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User temp = new User()
        {
            Name = "test1"
        };
        Model.data = temp;
    }
}

public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        OnPropertyChanged(null);
        return true;
    }
}
public class Model : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private User m_data;
    public User data
    {
        get { return m_data; }
        set
        {
            SetField(ref m_data, value,"data");
        }
    }
}
public class User : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set
        {
            SetField(ref name, value, "Name");
        }
    }
    private string tel;
    public string Tel
    {
        get { return this.tel; }
        set
        {
            SetField(ref tel, value, "Tel");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're binding to `Model.data` - that is, the specific instance of `data` at that time. This never changes. I'm not really familiar with how binding works in Winforms, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894103/does-data-binding-support-nested-properties-in-windows-forms) may help.

Comment: @CharlesMager thanks. It helps a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your binding on `Model.data`, but later on, assign it a new value.
So the instance that is being monitored by the binding, is no more being used.

You've 2 options:

First one: don't create new `User`, just change it's `Name`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Model.data.Name = "test1";
}
```

Or, if you really need to support both case (creation and assigment), then you have to change the binding to the `Model` and take the text from `data.Name`:

```
label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Model, "data.Name", false, 
                        DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

And the `set` part of the `User` Property in the `Model` to this:

```
set
{
    SetField(ref m_data, value, "data");
    this.data.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => this.OnPropertyChanged("data");
}
```

So, this will create a `PropertyChanged` on the data, if `data.Name` has been changed, well if the `data` property itself has been `set`