# C# Winforms NumericUpDown Binding

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, argumentexception

When you bind property Value an exception is thrown:

> An exception of the type "System.ArgumentException" appeared in System.Windows.Forms.dll, but was not processed in user code
>
> For more information: For a composite DataBinding, the IList or
>   IListSource can serve as the data source.

**Form**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IPresenter<MainPresenter>
{
        private MainPresenter _presenter;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _presenter = new MainPresenter() { Current = this };
            numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", _presenter, nameof(_presenter.YearOfIssue), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

        }
}
```

**Presetner**

```
public class MainPresenter : PresenterBase, IView<MainForm>
{
        private decimal _yearOfIssue;
        private MainForm _form;

        public decimal YearOfIssue
        {
            get
            {
                return _yearOfIssue;
            }
            set
            {
                _yearOfIssue = value;
                OnChanged("YearOfIssue");
            }
        }
}
```

**Question**

**How to correctly bind the property "Value" in Control NumericUpDown?**

Comment: You assign to `Presenter`, but reference `_presenter`.  Why?

Comment: Try [Does data binding support nested properties in Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894977/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech, Sorry. It does not work

Comment: We don't have enough code to duplicate your issue since you hide things in your inheritance and interfaces from us.