# Winform TextBox databind to Listbox using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inotifypropertychanged, listboxitem

I have set up Entity Framework with my VB.NET project. I have a model class that takes the data from a table from my MS SQL Server DB. My ListBox object is filled from the model class. What I am trying to do is when a user clicks on an item on from the listbox the text box is populated with the data from the table. If the user clicks on a mustang the text boxes are filled with the model, make, and year of a mustang.

I am using INotifyPropertyChanged in a viewmodel class that I thought would allow me to get each part of the dataset.

This code shows only one part of the requirements to better simplify the post

```
Public Class CarViewModel
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private _SelectedCarModelName As CarModel

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged


Public Property SelectedCarModelName () As CarModel
    Get
        Return _SelectedCarModelName 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As CarModel)
        _SelectedCarModelName = value
        OnPropertyChanged("CarName")
    End Set
End Property

Public Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
End Class
```

My Textbox Data bind looks like this. My Textbox resides on the frm.vb.

```
txtCarName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _carViewModel.SelectedCarModelName.CarName, "CarName", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

When I click on an item on the list it will access the property, but it will not set the property change. I know I am doing something wrong but I just don't know what it is.

******UPDATED*******

ViewModel

```
Public Class CarViewModel
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private _SelectedCarModelName As CarModel

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Public Property SelectedCarModelName As CarModel
    Get
        Return _SelectedCarModelName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As CarModel)
        _SelectedCarModelName= value
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCarModelName ")
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
End Class
```

Windows Form TextBox

**************Edited*******************

```
private _CarViewModel As CarViewModel
        Dim bs As New BindingSource(_CarViewModel , Nothing)
    txtCarName.DataBindings.Add _
("Text", bs, "SelectedCarModelName", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, String.Empty)
```

After I have restarted everything, for some reason my machine likes that, I am not getting an error anymore. When I debug the code is iterating through the Getter 3x, the number of fields. but it is not getting an output for the textbox.

Comment: See if [Does data binding support nested properties in Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894977/719186) solves the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech I have followed your link and used and did some changes. Now I am getting a system.argumentExceptionError "DataMember Property cannot be found on the datasource". You have any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see in your post what you declared for the DataMember.

Comment: @LarsTech from what I Understand    "CarName"  would be the datamember and my source is    _carViewModel.SelectedCarModelName . The    "CarName" is a field in the CarModel class

Comment: You're confusing me.  Update the post so we know what the code looks like now.

Comment: @LarsTech I really appreciate your help with this. I know it is very very simple for some, but I just don't like working with vb.net let along with winforms....Just not clean to me :)

Comment: Would help if you showed how you created the bs object.  Make sure to add `True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)` to your data binding call like you did before.  Also, you have to use the actual property name.  Change `OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName")` to `OnPropertyChanged("ChangedValue")`

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you for you help I left out how I created that. Sorry about that it is the Bindingsource object from the carviewmodel. I really do appreciate this help.

Comment: Your property names are all over the place.  You bind to "ChangedValue", but I don't see that property anywhere in your code.  You raise the `OnPropertyName("CarName")` but the property is called "SelectedCarModelName".  All those references to the property have to be the same.

Comment: @LarsTech I have changed the propertynames to the appropriate names and now I am getting a column isn't found in the collection. I have checked the model and I am spelling it correctly.

Comment: I don't see your project.  I only see what you posted above, and the code above does not have correct property names anywhere.

Comment: @LarsTech I updated the code to make a bit simpler. I am going to the to straight to the model and now my property objects say nothing, and it don't look like the onpropertychanged() is being raised...

Comment: So frustrating.  Your binding property is "DisplayName" but your class doesn't have that property.

Comment: @LarsTech Ok I took out the "DisplayName" and now it runs without error however I am not getting the CarName in the textbox. I am sorry for this inconvenience Lars. I really do appreciate your patience and help. I wish I understood this better.

Comment: Now I see "SelectedLightTypeDisplayName", but your class has "SelectedCarModelName".  You declare "_CarViewModel", don't initialize it, but bind to "_addLightViewModel".  You have to post the code that you are using.  This could have been solved hours ago.

Comment: @LarsTech Sorry that was a different code. but this is what I am using, my deepest apologies. Do I need to initialize _CarViewModel? I want to bind to the _CarViewModel, I believe, to get the data.